# perl cookbook fixstyle2 perplexed by & 1

Tags: perl

From once again perl cookbook, I know what this program does and I understand most of it but below code is escapes me.
It is using basically if else but what is ( $i++ & 1 ) mean??

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# fixstyle2 - like fixstyle but faster for many many matches
use strict;
my $verbose = (@ARGV && $ARGV[0] eq '-v' && shift);
my %change = ();
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($in, $out) = split /\s*=>\s*/;
    next unless $in && $out;
    $change{$in} = $out;
}
if (@ARGV) {
    $^I = ".orig";
} else {
    warn "$0: Reading from stdin\n" if -t STDIN;
}
while (<>) {
    my $i = 0;
    s/^(\s+)// && print $1;         # emit leading whitespace
    for (split /(\s+)/, $_, -1) {   # preserve trailing whitespace
        print( ($i++ & 1) ? $_ : ($change{$_} || $_));
    }
}
 __END__
analysed   analyzed
```

Comment: Which book are you using? Is this the O'Reilly Perl Cookbook? Which edition?

Comment: 2nd edition this is

Answer (score 1):

`$i++` returns the value of $i and increments $i afterwards. `&` is the "bitwise and" operator, so it takes the before mentioned value of $i and checks its last bit (as 1 in binary is 00..01).

As $i is incremented by 1 in each iteration, in binary its last bit changes from 1 to 0 and vice versa in each step, therefore the expression just determines odd versus even words.

Comment: Sorry how does that determine if current selection matches the key n therefore put replacement value?   N why is 1 there??

Comment: 1 is there because bitwise AND with 1 returns the last bit of the other operand. The replacement happens in the other part of the code, `$change{$_} || $_`.

Comment: what I am asking is(because I think I understand how ternary works),  ($i++ & 1) ? $_ : ($change{$_} || $_) says If ($i++ & 1) is true, then $_, if not, ($change{$_})..  I  1) .      is there some doc I can read up on this?

Comment: I thought whole point of program was to read another file and if it sees matching word(analysed in this example), replace it w/ analyzed. How does bit wise(which basically determins 1 or 0 based on val of $i being incremented) operation help you see that there is a matching word? That's the part I don't understand

Comment: Without seeing the input, I can only guess. It seems like there are pairs of words of which only one should be translated.

Comment: not sure why input is needed. My quesiton is, IF input matches analysed, I don't know how code itself is matching it??? That's the part I don't understand.

Comment: Split with a pair of capturing parents in it returns a list that alternates what split normally would return with whatever was captured (in this case, the whitespace).  So the $i++ & 1 ? ... : ... Is to make it do one thing for the whitespace and another for the nonwhitespace

Comment: But this whole thing is bizarre; I don't know why anyone would ever do this with split instead of s///g

Comment: Sorry @ysth, I have no idea what you are saying